# How to Bind a Value Property in LineSeries using LiveCharts

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, livecharts

I am wanting to bind the Values of each Line Series in WPF to a collection of values of type SeriesCollection in C#. For now, the each lines are assigned with solid values. How can I bind it to an a Collection? An example would be binding the 1st line series to the Series Collection below. Much appreciated!

```
<lvc:CartesianChart>
                    <lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
                        <lvc:LineSeries Title="Pres" Values="4,7,2,9,3" Visibility="{Binding PresVisibility, Converter={StaticResource bvc}}"/>
                        <lvc:LineSeries Title="Temp" Values="6,2,6,3,8" Visibility="{Binding TempVisibility, Converter={StaticResource bvc}}"/>
                        <lvc:LineSeries Title="Flow" Values="7,2,8,3,9" Visibility="{Binding FlowVisibility, Converter={StaticResource bvc}}"/>
                        <lvc:LineSeries Title="Control" Values="6,2,6,3,8" Visibility="{Binding ControlVisibility, Converter={StaticResource bvc}}"/>
                        <lvc:LineSeries Title="Compressor" Values="7,2,8,3,9" Visibility="{Binding CompressorVisibility, Converter={StaticResource bvc}}"/>
                    </lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
                    <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
                        <lvc:Axis Title="Time" Labels="{Binding CurrentLabels}"></lvc:Axis>
                    </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
                    <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
                        <lvc:Axis Name="yAxis" LabelFormatter="{Binding CurrentYFormatter}"></lvc:Axis>
                    </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
                </lvc:CartesianChart>
```

In C#:

```
public SeriesCollection PresSeries { get; set; }

PresSeries[0].Values.Add(ScrewState.GetScrewAll().V101.p);
            PresSeries[1].Values.Add(ScrewState.GetScrewAll().V102.p);
            PresSeries[2].Values.Add(ScrewState.GetScrewAll().P1.p);
            PresSeries[3].Values.Add(ScrewState.GetScrewAll().P2.p);
            PresSeries[4].Values.Add(ScrewState.GetScrewAll().P3.p);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define the `LineSeries` in XAML, you don't have to define a `SeriesCollection` anymore (you just did it in XAML - `<CartesianChart.Series>` is the `SeriesCollection`). It's sufficient to define the actual `ChartValues` source collection in C# (e.g., inside your view model):

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<lvc:CartesianChart x:Name="CartesianChart">
  <lvc:CartesianChart.DataContext>
    <local:LiveChartsModel />
  </lvc:CartesianChart.DataContext>

  <lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
    <lvc:LineSeries Title="Sine Graph"
                    Values="{Binding SineGraphValues}"
                    Configuration="{Binding DataMapper}"/>
  </lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
</lvc:CartesianChart>
```

**LiveChartsModel.cs**

```
public class LiveChartsModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public LiveChartsModel()
  {
    // Initialize the binding source
    this.SineGraphValues = new ChartValues<ObservablePoint>();

    // Plot a sine graph
    for (double x = 0; x <= 360; x++)
    {
      var point = new ObservablePoint() 
      { 
        X = x, 
        Y = Math.Sin(x * Math.PI / 180) 
      };

      this.SineGraphValues.Add(point);
    }

    // Setup the data mapper
    this.DataMapper = new CartesianMapper<ObservablePoint>()
      .X(point => point.X)
      .Y(point => point.Y)
      .Stroke(point => point.Y > 0.3 ? Brushes.Red : Brushes.LightGreen)
      .Fill(point => point.Y > 0.3 ? Brushes.Red : Brushes.LightGreen);
  }

  private object dataMapper;   
  public object DataMapper
  {
    get => this.dataMapper;
    set 
    { 
      this.dataMapper = value; 
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public ChartValues<ObservablePoint> SineGraphValues { get; }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) => this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Comment: thank you for explaining. Can I know why you chose to use dataMapper? Ans what is the purpose of using the PropertyChangedEventHandler?

Comment: @SophieChai When you use a custom data type as chart value e.g., `Point`, then you have to tell the chart which properties of the type are used to plot the chart's series and to which axis those properties map. The `CartesianMapper` describes such a mapping. Furthermore it allows to define constraints, that allow to e.g. assign a brush to color of the graph based on certain thresholds. You can also use this mapper to transform data points: `new CartesianMapper<Point>()
      .X(point => point.X)
      .Y(point => point.Y * 1.5)`.

Comment: `PropertyChangedEventHandler` is a delegate for the `PropertyChanged` event, which is a member of `INotifyPropertyChanged`. To prevent memory leaks, you should always implement this interface when your type (in this case `LiveChartsModel`) is the source for data binding. If the source for the data binding is a `DependencyObject` you should prefer to implement the properties as `DependencyProperty`.